# How to use diff command on git repo

Tags: git, diff, git-svn

How can I use the 'diff -u' command to generate patches that can be applied to a 'git/sv', repository? I am intending to run the diff command on a 'git-svn' repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating the patch on a Git repo (which a `git-svn` repo counts as), and planning to apply it to another Git/`git-svn` repo, then you should probably use Git's regular patch utilities (e.g. `git diff` and `git format-patch`).

Comment: I have used git diff but the caveat is that it produces a diff with git specific headers 'diff --git a/afile b/afile' which makes applying it on an svn repo a nightmare for my other teammates. I am more looking at generating a patch that will apply uniformly across repo - more like what tortoise svn generates.

Comment: Standard utilities like `patch` ignore that `diff --git` thing on header. What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: I use patch and it works well but the team does not want to use patch. They prefer to use eclipse > patch > apply. All I want is a way to use the unix diff command to generate a patch on a git-svn repo?

Comment: Maybe try the svn-compatible diff script listed here, then: http://mojodna.net/2009/02/24/my-work-git-workflow.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I would appreciate if you explained how to use diff to generate a patch.

Comment: this page has the answer I was looking for: https://trac.openxdata.org/wiki/UsingGitSvn